# How can I keep my program running when I use subprocess.call() to switch user?

Tags: python, subprocess

Whenever I run this program, it completes the first function perfectly and then ends the program before doing anything else. How can I allow the other two functions to run?

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["su", "my_user"])  # runs perfectly
print("user switched to my_user")  # does not run
subprocess.call(["cd", "../documents/my_code"])  # does not run
```

By the way, I am running this from a Linux terminal using ipython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't doing what you think it is.  When you run `su`, just as the function says, this runs as a subprocess.  That subprocess will start as `my_user` and immediately exit, but your Python process is unaffected.  You will still be the original user.

You can feed commands into that subprocess, assuming you need to run things as that other user, but your process isn't going to change.

**Followup**

`subprocess.call` waits for the command to finish.  The `su` command is going to create a new shell, logged in as the new user, and that shell will present a new prompt to you.  You probably thought your Python script had ended and you were back at the original prompt, but that's not the case.  The prompt you're seeing is from `su`, and you are the new user.  If you press Ctrl-D, then the `su` will exit, your script will continue, and you'll see your script type "user switched to my_user".  Thus, you are nested several shells deep and don't realize it.  ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how can I feed multiple commands into one subprocess? Also, why would this prevent print from working?

Comment: It's not clear this is what you want. `cd`, for example, isn't really useful as a subprocess, because it only affects that subprocess. It won't change the current working directory of  your Python script (that's what `os.chdir` is for). You can construct a string to execute with `sh -c`, but you are probably better off creating a single shell script for your Python script to execute, or simply figure out how to do what you want directly in Python.

Comment: I added a followup.